# Too many NSViews?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I want to build a controller with around 400 cells, 4 columns of 100 cells. Each of the cells must be drawn and respond to mouse events. Will this be too heavy? Should i use another approach like CALayer or NSCell for each cell?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not recommended to use hundreds (thousands..) of views for lightweight objects as they are pretty heavy-weight objects - just check out the [reference page for `NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class) to get an impression of the variety of stuff it handles.

We don't know much of your problem - could be a simple table, could be some kind of simple CAD application, could be anything else so it's hard to judge.

However, in any case you should at least consider implementing a single custom `NSView` instance and tracking the objects displayed as part of your custom implementation.
Tracking where a click in your custom view occurred isn't hard - especially if it's content is to be displayed in a highly regular fashion (table, tree view, ..).

You can check out Apple's **TreeView** example ([link to ADC site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TreeView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010131)) for a single view displaying structured content (there's also an accompanying WWDC session with background info on design decisions, implementation, etc.)

Comment: Well, i want to write a controller like an spreadsheet, or a grid, 4 or 5 x 100. Each cell will update with his own data, both text and graphics. Something like this. http://helpbets.com/images/articles/0000/0019/geeks_toy.jpg

Comment: And presumably you cannot use a `NSTableView` to get all the functionality for free..?

Comment: I'd just go with NSTableView also.